# Uploading image in email in rails 4.0.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am completely new to ROR. I am trying to create a simple application to create and send emails with attachment in rails 4.0.0. User should be able to embed image into email. The email is being sent and image is also uploaded but it gets corrupted in the process, so the recipient is not able to see it.
can anyone suggest a solution to this problem?

code for my mailer :

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => "xyz@abc.com"    

  def registration_confirmation(user)
    @user = user
    attachments['rails.jpg'] = File.read('C:\Ruby\mail\public\images\rails.jpg')
    mail(:to => "#{user.name} <#{user.email}>", :subject => "Image attachment")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
  def registration_confirmation(user)
    @user = user
    attachments['rails.jpg'] = File.read(Rails.root.join('public\images\rails.jpg'))
    mail(:to => "#{user.name} <#{user.email}>", :subject => "Image attachment")
  end
```

**Edit**:

Following your comment, I guess it could be a problem with the image. Check if the `rails.jpg` image exists in `YourRailsRoot/app/assets/images`, and then try using:

```
File.read(Rails.root.join('app/assets/images/rails.jpg'))
```

or

```
File.open(File.join(Rails.root, "/app/assets/images/rails.png"))
```

or, if you want to keep it in public, the same thing but changing the route

Comment: Have you checked the path to the image is correct?, Try adding it to your project and using `Rails.root` to locate it. For example: `File.read("#{Rails.root}/public/images/rails.png")` for your image.

Comment: yeahh.. chckd lyk u sd. path is correct. bt as usual in the mail its showing invalid image..

Comment: I've just tested it using `attachments["my_image.png"] = File.read( File.join(Rails.root, "/app/assets/images/my_image.png") )` with an image that's in `/rails_test/app/assets/images/my_image.png` and it's working fine. I don't know what else could be. Test in Rails 3?